# Why can pylance not resolve these imports? (python does)

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, pylance

This is in a virtual env, it is configured in vscode and tests run inside of VSCode Testing panel, and in a python shell and the import can most definitely be found by everything except pylance.

```
from celery import Celery # No error flagged by pylance

from celery.contrib.testing.worker import start_worker #import could not be resolved
from celery.contrib.testing import worker              #import could not be resolved
from celery.contrib import testing                     #import could not be resolved
from celery import contrib                             #import could not be resolved
```

How do you educate pylance about things that ARE definitely available?

Comment: Are you perhaps using the celery-types package for type stubs? I’m having the same problem, and I assume that Pylance fails to resolve the import because the `contrib` package does not actually exist in celery-types. It does resolve stuff that exists in celery-types as well.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm using and that is probably it.